# Is it possible to tell unordered_map to use vectors for its buckets instead of linked lists?

Tags: c++, stl

[This question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42588264/why-is-stdunordered-map-slow-and-can-i-use-it-more-effectively-to-alleviate-t) points to a talk that says unordered_map uses linked lists for its buckets. Is it possible to construct an instance of std::unordered_map that uses std::vectors as the container for its buckets?

Comment: No, you cannot change `std::unordered_map`.  You'd have to write your own or find one that already does.

Comment: Note that even if you did this, it would have to be something like a vector of pointers to dynamically allocated key-value pairs, not just a vector of pairs, in order to maintain the guarantees of reference invalidation promised by `std::unordered_map`. So you lose out on one of the main benefits of using a vector over a linked list, which is having your values tightly packed in one location in memory.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Though, you can provide an allocator to `std::unordered_map` if you want to improve data locality.