# Using Structured binding declaration in Range-based for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, c++17, structured-bindings

I am trying to combine two `std::map` containers (say `std::map<int, int> foo, bar`) into a third `std::map` (say `std::map<int, int> foobar`).

I know that I can achieve this using iterators as below:

```
    std::map<int, int>::iterator itr1 = foo.begin();
    std::map<int, int>::iterator itr2 = bar.begin();

    for (; itr1 != foo.end() && itr2 != bar.end(); ++itr1, ++itr2) 
    {
      foobar[itr1->first] += itr1->second;
      foobar[itr2->first] += itr2->second;
    }
```

But how can I use Range-based for loop (and maybe, in conjunction with Structured binding declaration) to achieve the same?

Or is there any better way to combine these two associative containers?

EDIT: The expected answer to this question should take two containers (`std::map` here) and combine them into a single union/united map with the keys being from both the respective associative containers and the values of duplicate keys being added.

**Example:**
If given `std::map` containers `foo` and `bar` are:

```
  std::map<int, int> foo = {{1, 10}, {2, 20}, {3, 30}};
  std::map<int, int> bar = {{3, 50}, {4, 60}};
```

Then `foobar' should be:

```
  std::map<int, int> foobar = {{1, 10}, {2, 20}, {3, 80}, {4, 60}};
```

This all done in a ***single Range-based for loop***.

Comment: Relevant question: [What's the best way to iterate over two or more containers simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12552277/580083)

Comment: just search for _C++ zip ranges_; this comes up all the time

Comment: seems like a dupe of [What's the best way to iterate over two or more containers simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12552277/whats-the-best-way-to-iterate-over-two-or-more-containers-simultaneously) - which covers both range-`for` and structured bindings.

Comment: @DanielLangr - Thanks! But the links in the top most answers there are broken.

Comment: Note that your loop will iterate off the end of the shorter container if the two containers have different sizes.

Answer (score 7):

> is there any better way to combine these two associative containers?

The easiest way is probably to iterate over them separately:

```
for(auto[k, v] : foo) foobar[k] += v;
for(auto[k, v] : bar) foobar[k] += v;
```

If you want to discard any data already in `foobar`:

```
foobar = foo;
for(auto[k, v] : bar) foobar[k] += v;
```

Answer (score -1):

There's a standard library algorithm for doing just this: [`std::set_union`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_union), in `<algorithm>`. Now, granted, it's ugly because it users iterator pairs, but you can probably improve that using ranges.

Anyway:

```
std::set_union(
    foo.begin(), foo.end(), 
    bar.begin(), bar.end(),
    std::inserter(foobar, foobar.begin())
);
```

should do the trick.

---

<sub>PS - This may be a bit slow - as [`std::map` itself is really slow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42588384/1593077). I assume you don't care about performance with this map (or it's really smaller), otherwise you shouldn't be using it.</sub>

Comment: Your code produces : foobar = {{1, 10}, {2, 20}, {3, 30}, {4, 60}};                           
                   Expected foobar = {{1, 10}, {2, 20}, {3, 80}, {4, 60}};