# How to find element in map where key is a shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a map of `std::shared_ptr`'s for both key and value and I'm trying to find the right element. Below is what I have, though, it still has a problem and won't compile.

```
std::map<std::shared_ptr<MyObjA>, std::shared_ptr<ValObj>> aobjs;
std::map<std::shared_ptr<MyObjB>, std::shared_ptr<ValObj>> bobjs;

template <typename T>
int findit(T& t)
{
    T myobj = t;

    typename std::map<std::shared_ptr<T>, std::shared_ptr<ValObj>>::iterator it;

    if constexpr(std::is_same<T, net::MyObjB>::value) {
        net::MyObjB objB;
    
        // failing here ...
        auto it = std::find_if(bobjs.begin(), bobjs.end(), 
                [&](std::shared_ptr<MyObjB> const& p) {
            return *p == objB;
        });

        if (it != bobjs.end()) {
            // found it
        
            return 0;
        }
    }
    
    return -1;
}
```

I think the problem is with the `first` and `last` of the `find_if` returning the `std::shared_ptr`, but unsure. I got a ton of output that I've had trouble parsing ...

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/include/g++-v10/bits/predefined_ops.h: In instantiation of ‘constexpr bool __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_pred<_Predicate>::operator()(_Iterator) [with _Iterator = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::shared_ptr<MyObjB>, std::shared_ptr<ValObj> > >; _Predicate = findit<MyObjB>::<lambda(const std::shared_ptr<MyObjB>&)>]’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/include/g++-v10/bits/stl_algobase.h:1912:42:   required from ‘constexpr _InputIterator std::__find_if(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _Predicate, std::input_iterator_tag) [with _InputIterator = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::shared_ptr<MyObjB>, std::shared_ptr<ValObj> > >; _Predicate = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_pred<findit<MyObjB>::<lambda(const std::shared_ptr<MyObj>&)> >]’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/include/g++-v10/bits/stl_algobase.h:1974:23:   required from ‘constexpr _Iterator std::__find_if(_Iterator, _Iterator, _Predicate) [with _Iterator = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::shared_ptr<MyObjB>, std::shared_ptr<ValObj> > >; _Predicate = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_pred<findit<MyObjB>::<lambda(const std::shared_ptr<ValObj>&)> >]’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/include/g++-v10/bits/stl_algo.h:3934:28:   required from ‘constexpr _IIter std::find_if(_IIter, _IIter, _Predicate) [with _IIter = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::shared_ptr<MyObjB>, std::shared_ptr<ValObj> > >; _Predicate = findit<MyObjB>::<lambda(const std::shared_ptr<MyObjB>&)>]’
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Please [edit] and show a [mcve]

Comment: This function signature is not correct: `int findit<T& t>`. That should be a pretty easy error to fix.

Comment: @TedLyngmo - yeah, typo, fixed.

Comment: `template <typenameT>`...? `std::shared_ptr<VObj>`? What is `VObj`? It'd be better if you actually made a [mre] and _copied_ it into the question.

Comment: Working it now, it'll take me a bit.

Comment: `std::find_if` requires a predicate that accepts the `value_type` of the container searched.  The _value type_ of `std::map` is `std::pair<const Key, T>`.

Comment: `std::map` has its own [`find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) method to search for a key. Don't use `std::find_if()`. Just note that `std::map`'s default compare requires the key type to support `operator<`, which `std::shared_ptr` supports prior to C++20, but `operator<` is removed for `std::shared_ptr` in C++20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a map of `std::shared_ptr`'s for both key and value
>
> ... thoughts?

A few things come to mind:

1.
It is likely not a good idea to hold a map like that - especially with respect to the keys. It doesn't make sense to have "heavy" keys, that require resource allocation, and which you are likely avoiding holding many copies of.

It is likely that `MyObjA`'s have some kind of cheap numeric identifier you can use; and if they don't - consider adding such a field, and constructing `MyObjA` with such a unique identifier. Then, instead of a map from MyObjA's to MyObjB's, you could map from ObjAKey to MyObjB's, or even from ObjAKey to `std::pair`'s of a MyObjA and MyObjB.

2.
I suspect that even for the map *values*, a `std::shared_ptr` may not be necessary, but you haven't given us enough context.

3.
Do you really need an *ordered* map? Would `std::unordered_map` not work for you? Also, if the number of elements in your map is not big enough, you can probably just use a vector of MyObjA, MyObjB pairs and it'll be good enough. [It's not as though the standard library maps are fast](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42588384/1593077).